# How can I get the updated date from a braintree usBankAccount payment method through the Braintreee API using JAVA

Tags: java, paypal, braintree

Using JAVA:

This works for credit card payment methods:

```
 CreditCard card = (CreditCard) paymentMethodToken;
 Calendar cal2  = card.getUpdatedAt();
```

But this fails with a maven build error:

```
 UsBankAccount usBankAccount = (UsBankAccount) paymentMethodToken;
 Calendar cal3  = usBankAccount.getUpdatedAt();
```

Error:

> /C:/lplr/zmmpnb/JavaProject/src/main/java/org/nazarene/zmmpnb/ZGLOBAL1_Operation.java:[1439,40] cannot find symbol
> [ERROR]   symbol:   method getUpdatedAt()
> [ERROR]   location: variable usBankAccount of type
> com.braintreegateway.UsBankAccount

I am using import com.braintreegateway.*;

When I look at the braintree repo for usBankAccount on git (https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java) there does not seem to be a reference to `getUpdatedAt()` even though the Braintree developer docs says `getUpdatedAt(`) is one of the attributes of `usBankAccount`.
(https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/response/us-bank-account/java)

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to BrainTree JDK 3.29.0 and getUpdatedAt() now works for US Bank Accounts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).